# Java Regex Matcher not giving expected result

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code.

```
String _partsPattern = "(.*)((\n\n)|(\n)|(.))";
static final Pattern partsPattern = Pattern.compile(_partsPattern);
String text= "PART1: 01/02/03\r\nFindings:no smoking";
Matcher match = partsPattern.matcher(text);
while (match.find()) {
System.out.println( match.group(1));
return; //I just care on the first match for this purpose

      }
```

Output: **PART1: 01/02/0**
I was expecting **PART1: 01/02/03** why is the 3 at the end of my text not matching in my result.

Comment: It seems to be working as you want. You can check here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture?  Is it always PART#: date?

Comment: On second thoughts, you want to match everything that occurs before the occurrence of 1 or 2 newline chars. You could simplify the regex to (.*)(\n{1,2}). Do you really want the last `(.)`? That will match any character.

Comment: Running your code I get: `PART1: 01/02/03` and then (second match): `Findings:no smokin`

Comment: If you want just first match then don't use `while (match.find()) {` but `if (match.find()) {`. This way you will remove unnecessary `return` statement. Also last part of your regex is `(.)` which in case there will be no line separators will hold last character from entire match, so this may be reason why instead of `PART1: 01/02/03` you see `PART1: 01/02/0` - `3` may be in group(5).

Comment: @Pshemo I don't want only first match. Just for this example I made a return to simplify it.

Comment: So can you [[edit]] your question with more details about what you really want, what you have and post [short code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could copy-paste to your IDEs to reproduce problem you are facing? The one you posted seems to be working correct since it returns `PART1: 01/02/03` as you wished.

Comment: I just edited it.Added \r to my string to be the same as my actual code. String text= "PART1: 01/02/03\r\nFindings:no smoking";

Comment: Thanks @Chthonic Project  (.*)(\n{1,2}) is better than what I am using right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your regex is that `.` will not match line separators like `\r` or `\n` so your regex will stop before `\r` and since last part of your regex

```
(.*)((\n\n)|(\n)|(.))
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is required and it can't match `\r` last character will be stored in `(.)`.

If you don't want to include these line separators in your match just use `"(.*)$";` pattern with `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag to make `$` match end of each line (it will represent standard line separators like `\r` or `\r\n` or `\n` but will not include them in match).

So try with

```
String _partsPattern = "(.*)$"; //parenthesis are not required now
final Pattern partsPattern = Pattern.compile(_partsPattern,Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

---

Other approach would be changing your regex to something like `(.*)((\r\n)|(\n)|(.))` or `(.*)((\r?\n)|(.))` but I am not sure what would be the purpose of last `(.)` (I would probably remove it). It is just variation of your original regex.

Comment: Thanks very much Pshemo6 that works for me. Can you explain in more detail on why mine is ripping of the last char (just for my knowledge) . I could not vote up your answer because I do not have enough reputations to do so.

Comment: @HelenAraya As I mentioned earlier your regex contains `(\n\n)|(\n)|(.)` part and since there is no `?` or `*` after it this part is mandatory. Since `\n\n` or `\n` or `(.)` will not match `\r` or `\r\n` in your string first regex matcher will stop before `\r`. Now as I mentioned earlier this part is mandatory regex has to put there something and only thing that can be used is `(.)` and it will store your last matching character before `\r`. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Works, giving `"PART1: 01/02/03 "`. So my guess is that in the real code you read the `text` maybe with a `Reader.readLine` and erroneously strip a carriage return + linefeed. Far fetched but I cannot imagine otherwise. (readLine strips the newline itself.)

Comment: I have edited my question. The input text is now String text= "PART1: 01/02/03\r\nFindings:no smoking"; I added \r before \n